How to pull pub/sub messages serially
Hi I am using pub/sub for one Job, where my requirement is that subscriber should not ack the message immediately.
I am using below piece of code
  ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
      subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, messageReceiver).build();
      subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
      subscriber.awaitTerminated();

Code reference Link
But in Response i am seeing that its polling the same message from the queue as there is no ack() happened for the message.
Is there a way to handle this scenario ?
Tried : I tried using the subscriber.isRunning(); method. If this method is running don't ack the message. But this is also not working.
Expected: It should not poll in between if there is no ack().

When you say "not ack the message immediately," when should the message be acked? When you say "not poll in between," what do you mean? Are you running the code above multilple times and expecting the message not to get redelivered? How long in between the runs?

A PubSub message must be ack in the 10s by default. You can change the ack timeline to 10 minutes max. In the pull subscription, you can also extend the ack deadline programmatically; but never beyond 10 minutes. Does it fit your requirements?

Note that if using the client library as indicated given the sample code provided, the subscription-configured ack deadline isn't so relevant because the client library sets deadlines on messages itself and extends the ack deadlines on its own (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/lease-management).
